# Are small monsters synchronized among hunters?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

In previous Monster Hunter games, when two or more players were hunting together, the same small monsters would appear for all players, but their position and behaviour was not the same for everyone. It was common to see another hunter swipe at empty air and a small monster die to nothing a few meters away.

The given reason for this behaviour was that synchronizing small monsters would take up precious processing power while not being all that noticeable in a hunt. Now that Monster Hunter is on newer consoles which might have more processing power to spare, are small monsters synchronized among all hunters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After completing several small monsters quests in multiplayer, I feel confident saying that small monsters are synchronized among all hunters, as I've never once experienced any incongruencies seen in previous games.

Answer (score -1):

Large monsters are synced always but small monsters are client side mostly, with a couple of parameters been synced. Depending on the console power, entering the area in the same time and possibly many other factors , I have encountered occasions when some small monsters were synced and others not.

So syncing the small ones seems to be dependent on numerous factors even for the new consoles.